# Hover underlining only text within a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I'm trying to get an underline to work on `hover` on a vertical `nav` made with `flexbox`. On a horizontal `nav` without `flexbox` the `hover` underline works fine, but as soon as `flexbox` is added the underline spans the entire box rather than just under the text.

See how in the first snippet below it works as intended but as soon as I make `main_nav` vertical with `flexbox` in the second snippet the underline breaks.

How can I fix this so it underlines correctly while keeping the `nav` vertical?

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}


#wrapper #main_nav {
  //display: flex;
  //flex-direction: column;
}

.nav_item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block
}

.nav_item:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav_item:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="main_nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item1</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item2</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item3</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item4</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}


#wrapper #main_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav_item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block
}

.nav_item:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav_item:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav id="main_nav">
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item1</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item2</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item3</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav_item">Item4</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-flex;` instead of `display:flex;`, which is block-level.

Answer (score 2):

By default, flexbox `stretch` the items.
For `flex-direction: column` configuration, you have to add `align-items: flex-start` to fix it.

```
#wrapper #main_nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```