# How to don't apply hover effects to content added in :before? css

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm adding '>' in :before property to links, but when apply the :hover effect also take the styles  `text-decoration: underline;` so, I need that don't apply the effect in the content added in :before, I tried resolve this whit this options

```
a:before {
  content: '> ';
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

a:before:hover {
  content: '>';
  pointer-events: none;
}

a:before:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

but none works.

this is how links behave with hover

[image: this is how links behave with :hover]

here is an example of my code, the structure, `<a>` inside `<p>` is because the content is from a text editor

```css
.super {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
    content: '> ';
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
  
  a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
  }
```

```html
<div class='super'>
<p>
<a href='https://google.com' target='_blanck'>Example to link</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you have shown here is not enough to see the problem you are having. Please include all of the relevant code in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem and be able to help.

Comment: The first mistake here is, hover will not apply on pseudo elements, so write a:hover:before,

Comment: Yes, we understand what is happening, but not how or why. Please include enough code to reproduce the problem (not an image) so we can actually see it and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I added a example of my code, can you run the snippet

Comment: The underline in your `:before` content is being caused by the `display:flex` in your CSS for `a`. The `a:before:hover` CSS rule is also incorrect as stated above, but in this case it doesn't make a difference - the correct usage won't prevent the underline from appearing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hover underlining only text within a flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562660/hover-underlining-only-text-within-a-flexbox)

Comment: No, I tried it , but don't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things in your code that stop if from working:

- The main reason is the use of **`display:flex`**
- you also have the incorrect order for **`:hover:before`** but that doesn't matter because it won't work with `display:flex` anyway.

With the default display for `a` elements, the text-underline doesn't affect the content added using the `:before` pseudo-element. However using `display:flex` changes how it is displayed and causes the text-underline to be added to the content added in `a:before` *as well as* the link text:

**Working example**:

UPDATE: To meet your *new* new requirement of indentation on a long link *and* not being able to change the HTML.

```css
.super {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

a:before {
    content: '>';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a:hover:before{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='super'>
<p>
<a href='https://google.com' target='_blanck'><span>This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link This is a very long link</span></a>
</p>
</div>
```

Also, FYI, the correct way to use `:hover` and `:before` together is `:hover:before`, but in this case it doesn't make a difference when you are using `display:flex`as you can see below:

Example using the correct CSS `a:hover:before` *with* `display:flex` (and as you can see it doesn't work):

```css
.super {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    left: 0px;
    display:flex;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
    content: '> ';
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration:none!important;
}
  
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
  }
a:hover::before {
    text-decoration:none!important;
  }
```

```html
<div class='super'>
<p>
<a href='https://google.com' target='_blanck'>Example to link</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem here is that I need use ````display:flex```` for ````<a>```` because to long links that use 2 lines I need align the second line after  ````>````

Comment: @Mike if you have specific requirements such as a link that goes onto multiple lines, you need to include them in the question so we can give you an answer that works for you! I've updated the answer to add an indent to the long link text.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good yet yo make questions, but in your example ````>```` have the underline on hover :(

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I was in the middle of updating my answer... check it again now. If you add a `<span>` around the link text, that will let you apply the hover to it instead of the whole `<a>` element

Comment: for any reason don't work, don't show me the underline on hover >.<

Comment: You can see it work in the answer, so there must be something different in your code. Have you changed the HTML *and* CSS to the same as the answer above? Including the CSS rule: `a:hover span{ text-decoration:underline;}` ?

Comment: yes I update my code, I copied / pasted your code, but for me don't work, only if I delete the span show me the underline

Comment: This `a:hover span{ text-decoration:underline;}` is the CSS rule that adds the underline to the span on hover, so take a look at it in your own code. - if you have the rule exactly like that, then you have something else interfering with the hover. Try giving it a class in the HTML and CSS. But it does work - you can see it in the answer, so you just need to figure out what other code you haven't shown us that is stopping it from working (I can't help with that when we can't see it!)

Comment: I don't have nothing else in my code, I have exactly the same, if I remove the ````text-decoration: none;```` from ````a{}```` show me the underline but this include ````>````

Comment: This is all my code that have interaction whit `<a>` elements `a {
  position: relative; 
  display: flex;
}

a::before {
  content: '>';
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a::hover span{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

  a:visited {
    color: #0071C5;
  }`

Comment: @Mike `a::hover span` is wrong... it should be `a:hover span` i.e. only one `:`

Comment: Answering your last comment, i have that code in my styles

`<div>
    <p><a href="/">Intel Security Newsroom</a></p>
    <p><a href="/">Security Center</a></p>
    <p><a href="/">Intel Bug Bounty Program</a></p>
    </div>` this is my HTML code, the code inside the div is generated from text editor, so I only reaad it from db, I don't add manually the links

Comment: @Mike OK, I've updated it again to work without changing the HTML. See if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly, thank so much, you save my life

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced location hover
`a:hover:before`

Comment: This isn't the reason the code isn't working as expected - the problem is because of `display:flex`.